# How can I call a m file script into simulink block which uses simout file?

Tags: matlab, controller, simulink

I have a simulink file and I'm working on designing a controller.

The file contains several electronics converters connected in parallel and each converter has a controller. The converter measures voltage and current and pass them to the controller to control.

The simulink file generates the simout file after simulation and that simout file is being used to calculate the impedance of the electrical grid in a m script file as a transfer function. I need to use the transfer function of impedance from the workspace in the place of " Req +sLeq" as in the purple marked position of the picture.

In other words, in my controller design, I need to call that m-file transfer function into a block and use the transfer function (impedance) as active damping during the simulation.

I'm not sure how can I call the transfer function from the m file (generated from simout) back to the simulink block during simulation.

The simulation need to be done in one go as closed loop system.

Please help me for this.[image]

Comment: I think it would help to include some examples of what you have tried already

Comment: Just edited. Kindly check again

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to solve this. First, you can try to use a Matlab function block:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html

Otherwise, you can always split your routines. Split your simulations, obtain your transfer function -which now exists in the workspace- then run your control system simulation using a separate file.

Dummy main-file

```
simOut = sim('electricalSimulation');   % Your first simulation
output = simOut.output;
input  = simOut.input;
electricalTf = obtainTF(output, input); % Your identification routine

sim('completeSystem');
```

Comment: The problem is the simulink simulation need to be done in one go and use the simout data in my controller as the feedback.

Comment: Is the "electricalTf" the function to find transfer function from the simout file ? Also, did you mean the controller simulink file by the "completeSystem"?

Comment: So let me clarify, you need to embed this sub electrical routine into your main simulation file. So you cannot split them. If this is the case, just simply construct an outer loop without identifying anything. That is, construct an outer loop for the electrical part of your simulation. Imagine a DC motor speed control schematic. First draw the electrical part using simscape, and then connect that electrical part to an outer loop motor control.

Or, you can use my first suggestion, the Matlab function. 

electricalTf is what your transfer function
completeSystem is controller plus plat

Comment: electricalTf should be a function that takes your inputs and outputs from the simulation file and identifies a transfer function. electricalTf returns that identified transfer function. 

completeSystem consists of your "identified electrical model" plus your mechanical dynamics plus your controller, and if you have it your sensor models, disturbance models etc. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Okay so, after checking your updated picture: the right way to do this is definitely Simscape electrical. So here is how you're going to do it: first design everything electrical using electrical toolbox components, then you're going to connect the electrical part to the simulink part using ps-simulink converter blocks. Notice that you do not need a transfer function anymore since you have modelled the system on the electrical side, you merely need to provide an input and feed the output back to your reference point and obtain an error which will be input for your controller.